# Android Push Notification Service

Tags: android, notification

I am trying to create a multiplayer game on Android. Right now, the user can see the list of Facebook friends and invite them to play. I would like  the user taps on a specific friend and automatically a push notification is sent to the other friend's device.
Which is the best service (meaning easiest and suitable) to implement this kind of solution?
(Firebase, pusher.io, pubnub ecc..)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite a definite answer, but you can see a list of some popular options here: https://stackshare.io/mobile-push-messaging

Comment: In the end I used Firebase hooking some cloud functions on server side. It's very easy and I would definitely recommend it.